# Analysis, limit of a complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, limits

Find the limit of $$z_n = n^2 \exp \left( \frac {\sin n + \textrm i \pi n^2} {4n \sqrt {n^2 + \textrm i + 1} } \right) \frac 1 {\sqrt {n^4 + n^2 + 2 \textrm i} }$$ and express your answer in the form $a + b \textrm i$, where $a, b \in \Bbb R$.

Sadly I have no access to the solution. I think you somehow have to split up the fraction into its real and imaginary parts and find the limit of each of these sequences respectively. I just cannot find a way to do that. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.SE. Please take some time to read the help page, especially this section ["MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), in order to correctly format your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: Try to show

$$\frac{n^2}{\sqrt {n^4 + n^2 + i}} \to 1.$$

This is not too bad, really. (If the $i$ was instead $1,$ it would be a beginning calculus problem, right?)

As for the exponential, think of it as $e^{a_n+ib_n}.$ Seems to me $a_n \to 0,b_n \to \pi/4.$